# Latex table does not put the borderline in the table with figures inside cells

Tags: latex, figure

I try to put three figures in latex documents, and I insert them inside table. Unfortunately, the table does not provide equal borders for each cells.
What's wrong?

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\extralabel[2]{{\edef\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel#2}\label{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \\
\includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{example-image-b} \\ \hline
\textbf{(a)}  & \textbf{(b)} & \textbf{(c)}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{ \textbf{(a)} Some text
\textbf{(b)} Some text
\textbf{(c)} Some text
}
\label{fig:Name}
\extralabel{fig:Name:a}{(a)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:b}{(b)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:c}{(c)}
\end{figure}
```

That is figure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your first line, the one with `\hline \\`, only has one cell. If you want to see all the vertical lines, you have to add as many cells as your table has columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\extralabel[2]{{\edef\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel#2}\label{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline && \\
\includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{example-image-b} \\ \hline
\textbf{(a)}  & \textbf{(b)} & \textbf{(c)}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{ \textbf{(a)} Some text
\textbf{(b)} Some text
\textbf{(c)} Some text
}
\label{fig:Name}
\extralabel{fig:Name:a}{(a)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:b}{(b)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:c}{(c)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```